# Extract numbers from a url's string group using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a url which has this format:

https://address.com/somestring/somestring-2/c100.200.3.4/somestrigx3/somestring.4

I want to obtain the number from c100.200.3.4 which are delimited by c and / and a dot. So in the end I want to have 100, 200, 3, 4.

I was wondering if there is a way to build a regex pattern for this instead of the classic string search and compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get with 1 regex, but with a bit of code.

```
String s = "https://address.com/somestring/somestring-2/c100.200.3.4/somestrigx3/somestring.4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=/c)(\\d+)|(?!^)\\G\\.(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null)
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    if (matcher.group(2) != null)
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/NxAsqi)

The regex `(?<=/c)(\d+)|(?!^)\G\.(\d+)` contains two alternatives: `(?<=/c)(\d+)` matches and captures into Group 1 any sequence of digits after `/c`, and the `(?!^)\G\.(\d+)` matches consecutive sequences of a literal `.` and digits (capturing the latter into Group 2) *after the successful previous match* (due to `(?!^)\G`). Since either group  can be non-initialized, we have to check it for null.

**UPDATE**

Since - as it turns out - the number of digit groups is a fix one (4), you can use a simpler regex with capturing groups:

```
String s = "https://address.com/somestring/somestring-2/c100.200.3.4/somestrigx3/somestring.4";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=/c)(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/2CsToZ)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer

Comment: how about using a simpler regex, for instance `Pattern.compile("c(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+)")` this would return the whole cxx.xx.xx.xx string and then I can split it and make it easier to extract the values, rather from the `while`. The only small issue would be getting rid of starting c from the first string split.

Comment: @Alin, there are several solutions, but from the start, it was not clear how many digit sequences there can be in the input string. My suggestion is universal, it supports any number of digit sequences separated with a dot. Yours will only capture a specified number of groups. You do not need to get rid of the starting `c`, you will just need to access the groups with the corresponding indices. And do not forget to escape dots in the pattern to match literal dots.

Comment: There will always be either 4 groups of digits or either none, meaning that the cxx.xx.xx.xx either is present in this form, or not. Your solution which is great for universal makes it harder for me to assign the numbers to specific variables. I'll see if I can mix my regex with your solution to take out the c character. Does this look ok to you `"(?<=/c)((\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+))"`

Comment: I posted another demo with the simplified regex. If you have several strings, change `if` to `while`. Variables can be assigned inside the `if/while`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String splits[] = input_url.replaceAll(".*?/c([0-9.]+)/.*", "$1").split("[.]");
```

Here, first it is picking the text in between `/c(...)/` at group `$1` and replacing the whole string with the captured group. After that it is splitting the string with a dot.